# TinyMCE v5 - iframe in dialog

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

The new TinyMCE v5 has removed support for iframes in dialogs, and from what I can see of the documentation, no explanation as to why, nor how to go about implementing an alternative.

I want to implement a custom Image/File Explorer UI to allow an author to either:

- select an existing image from/upload new image to an image library,
- browse for an existing document in a document library.

Without an iframe to host this complex UI, how can I achieve this? In v4 the RoxyFileManager could be used. In v5, no more, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

Neil -

We are aware that this capability is something that is negatively impacting some of our customers and we do intend on bringing this capability back in TinyMCE 5.

In the interim we would recommend staying on TinyMCE 4.

I would note that there is an issue in the TinyMCE Issue Tracker around this general topic:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4786

I would recommend adding your thoughts to that issue so our Engineering team are aware of your needs in this area.  Subscribing to that would also let you know when we address this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Issue tracker. The contribution from "mutekellim" looks interesting.